# Why display grid with 100% in grid-template-columns goes out of body?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
.parent {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  top:14px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:40% 60%;
  grid-gap:5px;
  background:#eee;
}
.left {
  border:2px solid red;
}
.right {
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='left'>LEFT</div>
  <div class='right'>RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

if position is not `fixed` there is no problem, but if position is `fixed` - `parent` is not entire visible on the right side.

Comment: why you should have position fixed?

Comment: @BhargavChudasama, because on the left side I have some menu, and on the right - a large content.

Comment: so use bootstrap for that for better menu and content dipslay [see here](https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar)

Comment: @BhargavChudasama, no thanks. Keep entire framework just for align a div...

Comment: for kind information `bootstrap` is not framework its library for make website responsive

Comment: so you can please add more info hows your page display without that we can not help you

Answer (score 6):

The issue isn't with **width:100%** like you think. It is with `grid-template` that you made `40% 60%` and you also have a `grid-gap` of `5px` which will make the total more than `100%`.

Instead rely on the  `fr` unit to split the free space considering the gap:

```css
.parent {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  top:14px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:4fr 6fr;
  grid-gap:5px;
  background:#eee;
}
.left {
  border:2px solid red;
}
.right {
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='left'>LEFT</div>
  <div class='right'>RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: even if we convert existing percent to fr then it also works like a charm.