# Why the forced horizontal scroll on two 50% CSS grid columns?

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

Why does explicitly setting two CSS Grid columns to 50% each create a horizontal scroll beyond 100% of the viewport width?

[This codepen shows the behavior I'm asking about.](https://codepen.io/bzelip/pen/NLObYo)

Basically, when the grid is set to the following css, it produces a two-column layout ***with no forced horizontal scroll*** beyond the viewport width:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 50%;
  grid-template-areas: 'item item';
}
```

When `grid-template-columns` is changed to explicitly set both column widths, the result is a two-column layout ***with a horizontal scroll***:

```
.grid {
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}
```

Why is the horizontal scroll present in the second context, but not the first?

edit: `<aside>`I seem to remember flexbox behaves in a similar fashion`</aside>`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 50%;
  grid-template-areas: 'item item';
}

/* WHY THE HORIZONTAL SCROLL 
   WHEN LINES 21-23 ARE
   UNCOMMENTED?! */

/* .grid {
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
} */

.item {
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.p1 {
  padding: .5rem;
}

code {
  padding: .5rem;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  font-weight: regular;
}
```

```html
<header class="p1">
  <h1>Why does the horizontal scroll happen when <code>.grid { grid-template-columns: 50% 50%; }</code></h1>
  <p>Uncomment lines 21-23 in the CSS of this codepen to set the above <code>.grid</code> css rule. See this <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/52374483/2145103">Stack Overflow post for discussion.</a></p>
</header>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Work with fr units: grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; I don't have the specifics at hand, but AFAIK, fr is a "flex unit" that refers to the amount of remaining space (discounting padding, etc.). Apparently, percentual values don't take those into consideration and the effective sizes overflow the horizontal client size.

Comment: a similar issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113420/display-grid-and-position-fixed-goes-out-of-body/52115646#52115646

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code (version 1):

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 50%;
  grid-template-areas: 'item item';
}
```

This will not overflow the container.

Two explicit columns are created by `grid-template-areas`.

The first column's width is set by `grid-template-columns` to 50%.

The second column's width is not set. Therefore, `grid-template-columns` computes to `none` ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing)).

The [grid spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#valdef-grid-template-rows-none) doesn't appear to go into detail about how `grid-template-columns: none` should apply to an explicit track. But here's what Chrome, Firefox and Edge are doing:

- Even though the second column is explicit, because it's defined by `grid-template-areas`, for track sizing purposes it's considered `implicit`, because `grid-template-columns` hasn't been defined.
- Therefore, the second column is being sized by `grid-auto-columns`, the sizing function for implicit columns ([demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BOqrJB)).
- The default value of `grid-auto-columns` is `auto` ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#implicit-grids)), which renders a lot like `1fr` in many cases, [by definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#valdef-grid-template-columns-auto)).
- So the second column is only consuming remaining space, which causes it to fill the row. No overflow is triggered.

---

Your code (version 2):

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-areas: 'item item';
}
```

This one is much easier to follow. Yes, this will clearly overflow the container:

```
50% + 50% + 1rem > 100%
```

---

Related:

- [The difference between percentage and fr units in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45090726/3597276)

Comment: why is `50% + 50% + 1rem > 100%` even though `box-sizing: border-box; ` is set to the grid?

Comment: Because `grid-gap` is not covered by the `box-sizing` property. Why would it be? It's not a component of the "[box model"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45059944/3597276)".

Comment: And we wonder why the internet looks like a mess...the spec is where the mess starts.